# How to pass interface to react useState in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass the interface down to react `useState` but im getting this error when doing so.

> Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'EditProfileInterface | (() => EditProfileInterface)'

What am i doing wrong ? I'm trying to tell typescript to check that `bio` is a string. I know i can do something like `useState<String>('')` but i want to use an interface.

```
interface EditProfileInterface {
    bio: string;
    gravatar: string;
}

function EditProfile(props: any) {
    const [bio, setBio] = useState<EditProfileInterface>('');
    .....
}
```

Comment: This could be caused by a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32465#issuecomment-569798304) in array descructuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be doing this instead:

```
const [bio, setBio] = useState<EditProfileInterface['bio']>('');
```

This will narrow down the specific property that you need (`bio`) within `EditProfileInterface` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a string (`''`) as default value but use `EditProfileInterface` as type. `EditProfileInterface` is an interface defining two properties that are strings.